# MultiValueDictKeyError in Django Login and Registration project

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Login and Registration page, but keep hitting this error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /pokesregister/
"'name'"
```

Below is my views.py code (along with lines commented out form various things I've tried based on google searching):

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, redirect
from .models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse



def index(request):

    return render(request, 'poke/index.html')

def login(request):
    print '*'*75
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_tuple = User.userManager.login(request.POST['email'], request.POST['password'])

        if user_tuple[0]: # true or false from the returned tuple
            request.session['id'] = user_tuple[1].id
            request.session['name'] = user_tuple[1].name + " " + user_tuple[1].alias        

            return render(request, 'poke/pokes.html')

        else:
            return render(request,'poke/pokes.html', user_tuple[1])
    return HttpResponse('login')

def register(request):
    print '*'*75
    print request.POST['name']
    user_tuple = User.userManager.register(request.POST['name'], request.POST['alias'], request.POST['email'], request.POST['password'], request.POST['confirm_password'], request.POST['dob'])
    # name = request.POST.get('name')
    # user_tuple = User.userManager.register(request.GET.get('name', False), request.GET.get('alias', False), request.GET.get('email', False), request.GET.get('password', False), request.GET.get('confirm_password', False), request.GET.get('dob', False))

    if user_tuple[0]:
        return render(request, 'poke/pokes.html', user_tuple[1])

    else:
        return render(request, 'poke/index.html', user_tuple[1])
```

And below is my models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import bcrypt
from django.db import models
import re
EMAIL_REGEX = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9.+_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+.[a-zA-Z]*$')

class UserManager(models.Manager):
    def login(self, email, password):
        try:
            user = self.get(email__iexact=email) # case insensitive comparison
            user2 = self.filter(email__iexact=email)
            print user
            print user2
            print user.password
            if user and bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'),user.password.encode('utf-8')) == user.password.encode('utf-8'):
                return (True, user)
                # should be classified as a successful login event

            return(False,{"login": "login failed"})
        except:
            print "Failed"
            return(False,{"login": "login failed"})

    def register(self, name, alias, email, password, confirm_password, dob):
        errors = {}

        if len(name) < 2:
            errors['name'] = "Name is too short"
        if len(alias) < 2:
            errors['alias'] = "Alias is too short"
        if len(password) < 8:
            errors['password'] = "Password is too short"
        if password != confirm_password:
            errors['confirm_password'] = "Passwords must match"
        try:
            if user == self.get(email__iexact=email):
                errors['invalid'] = "Invalid registration"
        except:
            pass
        if not EMAIL_REGEX.match(email):
            errors['email'] = "Please enter a valid email"

        if dob:
            pass

        if errors:
            return (False, errors)
        else:

        # register this person!
            password = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
            user = self.create(name=name, alias=alias, password=password, email=email, dob=dob)
            user.save()
            print(User.objects.all())
            return (True, {"Success":"success"})

class User(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    email = models.EmailField() # auto validation for us!
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pokes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dob = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    userManager = UserManager()
    objects = models.Manager()


class Pokers(models.Model):
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="f1")
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="f2")
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

Lastly, here's my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name = 'register'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, name = 'login'),
]
```

If anyone has any idea what could be going on here, I would really appreciate some advice. I've used this line previously, and made it work, but I'm not entirely sure how:

```
user_tuple = User.userManager.register(request.POST['name'],
request.POST['alias'], request.POST['email'],
request.POST['password'], request.POST['confirm_password'],
request.POST['dob'])
```

I apologize for any obvious errors, as I'm fairly new to all of this (obviously).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because the key you are trying to fetch ('name') is not there. If there is a situation where the user requests the register view without having the 'name' key, then it will throw an error.

Instead of:

```
request.POST['name']
```

Do:

```
request.POST.get('name', False);
```

If name doesn't exist, instead of throwing an error, the method returns False.

I would also recommend checking it is POST or GET similar to how you did in your login view. (if request.method == 'POST')

Comment: It looks like trying the above method gets me past the original error, but now produces a new one due to my validations. It's trying to validate the boolean instead of the value, which throws an error. I'll keep playing with it and see if I can figure out what's happening.

Comment: At that point I would do something along the lines of: 'if not request.POST.get('name', False) redirect(somewhere else)'

Comment: Or, you can replace False with a string that would be invalidated in the register function. A bit rough, but better than an error.